# Синхронизация кастомных настроек между экземплярами браузера

Tags: javascript, браузер

Есть скрипт для tampermonkey, который дает на конкретном сайте вести черный список авторов и скрывать их.

Вся работа ведётся с помощью `localStorage.setItem` и `localStorage.getItem`.

Хочется добавить возможность синхронизации между экземплярами браузера - помнится мне, было такое апи как минимум для залогненных в браузер пользователей, причем как на хроме, так и на firefox-е.

К сожалению, на js пишу очень редко и очень плохо, поэтому желателен максимально понятный пример, как достать и как засунуть в хранилище данные, как проверить есть ли поддержка синхронизации и вся связанная API-шка.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что для этого вместо юзерскрипта придётся писать полноценное расширение. Хотя вроде говорят, что storage.sync имеет ограничения, и даже расширение может случайно не помочь

Comment: @andreymal о блин, печально. Писать расширение ради такой мелочи пока не готов. А обходные варианты простые есть может какие?